# How to set backgound-color dynamically with scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I have a React component where I use a react datepicker input, and I have to set background-color for a  react datepicker selected month in a different color, based on a condition. This is how the calendar looks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0y5d.png)

I have to repeat this code multiple times but with a different background-color

```
 background-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

.blue react-datepicker__month-text {
 background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important;
 }

.green react-datepicker__month-text {
 background-color: green !important;
  color: white !important;
 }
```

Is it possible to set background -colour dynamically?
I have tried with

```
@function set-color($type) {
  @if($type == 'type 1 '){
    @return red ;
  }
  @if($type == 'type 2'){
     @return green ;
  }
}
@mixin dc($color) { 
 background-color: $color;
 
}
.react-datepicker__month-text {
  @include dc($type);
  color: white !important;
}
```

But then i don't know how to update $type value  with a value from the component.

Comment: set [css vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), then do `background-color:var(--datepicker_month-bg);color:var(--datepicker_month-text)`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I managed to fix it with css vars indeed.